# The If condition fails and goes to else

Tags: php, mysql

The if condition doesn't satisfies in $insertorderitems and the header location goes to checkout.php and not ordersucess.php

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'placeOrder' && $cart->total_items() > 0 && !empty($_SESSION['sessCustomerID'])){
    // insert order details into database
$insertOrder = $db->query("INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total_price, created, modified) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['sessCustomerID']."', '".$cart->total()."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");

    if($insertOrder){
        $orderID = $db->insert_id;
        $sql = '';
        // get cart items
        $cartItems = $cart->contents();
        foreach($cartItems as $item){
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO order_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('".$orderID."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['qty']."');";
        }
$insertOrderItems = $db->multi_query($sql);

        if($insertOrderItems){
            $cart->destroy();
            header("Location: orderSuccess.php?id=$orderID");
        }else{
            header("Location: checkout.php");
        }
```

Comment: then there must be something wrong with your query. your order_id and product_id must be an integer i think ..

Comment: what the issue?

Comment: Don't you need a separating semi colon (`;`) between the queries if you concatenate 'em?

Comment: @arkascha it is there

Comment: @Naren is the data getting saved?

Comment: please check the field type .. are they integer ?

Comment: First step, Try to echo $sql; and execute the query directly in the database;

Comment: you might be using some sql reserved words. Add backticks to your columns just to be safe.

Comment: your `foreach` loop should be `as key => $value`

Comment: @HankyPanky , The Order data is getting saved but the order_items data is not getting saved

Answer (score -1):

change your query to

```
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO order_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (".$orderID.", ".$item['id'].", ".$item['qty'].");";
```

order_id , product_id and quantity field are integer